# LC-3 - How to store input character then print input character with both input and output after strings?

Tags: lc3

I am trying to input a single character on the same line as a string and then output that character on a line with a string as well.  I have tried GETC and PUTC but I am getting the result of '0 I am really new to this LC-3 stuff and would really appreciate some help to get over this bump in the road.

Here is what I have so far.

```
    .ORIG x3000     ;start assembly directive

    MyMain  

    lea r0, input   ;point to input string
    trap    x22     ;print string out

    GETC

    ld  r0, newLine ;get <crlf>
    trap    x21     ;print it out

    lea r0, output  ;point to output string
    trap    x22     ;print string out

    PUTC

    ld  r0, newLine ;get <crlf>
    trap    x21     ;print it out

    lea r0, term    ;point to termination string
    trap    x22     ;print string out

    ld  r0, newLine ;get <crlf>
    trap    x21     ;print it out

    MyMainEnd   trap    x25     ;stop the program

    ; constants

    newLine     .FILL       x0A     ;line feed and Carriage return in LC-3
    input       .STRINGZ    "Please input a character: "
    output      .STRINGZ    "You input the character: "

    term        .STRINGZ    "Program execution terminated!"

    .END        ;end assembly directive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation for GETC

GETC - Read a single character from the keyboard. The character is not echoed onto the console. Its ASCII code is copied into R0. The high 8 bits of R0 are cleared

Your issue is using R0 for everything as the ld r0, newline will clobber the character you read in.  After you call the GETC trap you will need to copy R0's value into some other register and then move it back to R0 when you want to call PUTC.

Also from your question you will need to call PUTC twice.  Immediately after your GETC and then after you output the new line character.